# Why is my page randomly blank (no html returned)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a single page in my Laravel Application which returns often just a blank page.

Its just a normal blade which is used in controller like this:

```
public function changeusername()
{
    $title     = trans('menu.change_email');
    $sub_title = trans('menu.change_email');
    $base      = trans('menu.change_email');
    $method    = trans('menu.change_email');


    return view('app.admin.users.changeusername', compact('title', 'sub_title', 'base', 'method'));

}
```

I know it makes no sense to use trans in controller (especially not copying  times the same value) but I don't want to refactor yet.

In the console, I find this error:

> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The
> document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations
> if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range.
> The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or
> in the transfer protocol.

When checking the source code, its empty. Looks like no HTML was returned.

When I press F5 quickly after the first load then the source code contains HTML and everything seems to work.

I experience the same behavior in Chrome. Sometimes the source code is empty, and no warning in console. When I press F5 quickly after a failed load, the page is shown. I also cleared the view cache `view:clear`.

It seems that the page is only shown after consecutive loading. I tested this problem for this page on 4 different environments - it fails on 1 as descriped here, it returns an 500 error on the second, and it works on my laptop and on another server. No idea why.

Any ideas what could cause it?

I also noticed, that when the pages loades, the source code starts with a whitespace:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="no-js ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]>   <![endif]-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/website"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

However, on those two machines where it does not fail, there is no whitespace:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
```

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: @sta Laravel 5.6.39

Comment: Can you please try ```<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">```